# Timers in Spritekit and objective-C

Tags: objective-c, timer

So I am trying to incorperate a timer into my project which will gradually decrease. For example, a timer with 3 seconds on it will eventually be at 0 after 3 seconds have passed. I asked this question prior to this question and I got a response about using `NSTimeInterval`'s and this is how I set it up in my code:

```
@implementation MyScene {
    NSTimeInterval _timestamp;
}
```

When the timer starts:

```
_timestamp = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
Check your timer in your update pass:

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(_timestamp != nil && currentTime - _timestamp.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate >= 3.0) {
        // Perform your timer event
    }

    // Other updates
}
```

However this gives me a couple of errors on the first line in the update: The errors are:

```
member reference base type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') is not a structure or union

Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') and 'void )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the declaration of `_timestamp` to:

```
NSDate *_timestamp;
```

and change:

```
_timestamp = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

to:

```
_timestamp = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: Thanks maddy, Im sure I see you everywhere :D